# Why sum is getting nan as the output?

Tags: c, nan

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int input, j;
    float sum;
    for (j = 1; j <= 2; j++) {
        printf("Enter the mark for module %d ", j);
        scanf("%d", &input);
        sum += input;
    }
    printf("The Sum is: %f", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Inputs: `1,2`

Actual output: `nan`

Expected output: `3.000`

Comment: You never initialized `sum`. Turn on your compiler warnings and it should tell you about stuff like that.

Comment: [Always enable compiler warnings and read them](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57842756/995714). The compiler should tell you about the issue immediately

Comment: btw, you were lucky to get nan here. Some variation in the types, the compilers, the environment or sheer coincicence and your program would have given you the 'correct' result.

Comment: Just don't get the idea that the sum was guaranteed to be initialized to NaN, reading an uninitialized variable is called "Undefined behaviour"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [(Why) is using an uninitialized variable undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11962457/why-is-using-an-uninitialized-variable-undefined-behavior)

Answer (score 2):

Recent versions of clang with `-Wall` reports the following, which correctly diagnosis your problem:

https://godbolt.org/z/n4q1oTT1P

```
<source>:8:5: warning: variable 'sum' is uninitialized when used here [-Wuninitialized]
    8 |     sum += input;
      |     ^~~
<source>:4:12: note: initialize the variable 'sum' to silence this warning
    4 |   float sum;
      |            ^
      |             = 0.0
1 warning generated.
Compiler returned: 0
```

Comment: Please read: [What is a beginner-oriented canonical Q&A and how can it help me curate my watched tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426205) on the meta site.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the code. In your code, problem is in sum variable. You have to initialize the sum variable. Like this
float sum=0;

Answer (score -2):

its a logic error.initialize float sum =0 or float sum=1 as per the requirement of the question. Initialize sum as 0(in your case) and to what the input will get added to after running through the loop each time.